# Integrating brunch JS with maven

Tags: maven-3, brunch

I want to integrate the web artifacts part of my application with brunch.io.Could not find some descent google search for the same.
Can anybody help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Maven-exec](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to run a shell script that runs your `brunch build` command.

Reviewing this [article about maven/grunt integration](http://addyosmani.com/blog/making-maven-grunt/) will probably also be helpful, as the underlying concepts for running a Node.js tool from maven are basically the same.